# What is Adjusted Nett Gross?

Tags: profits

Can anybody explain to me Nett Gross, Adjusted Nett Gross and Total Nett Gross through an example? I am new to this subject and from an engineering background. This knowledge is required for my research work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A Google search of "adjusted nett gross" results in only ~8000 results. Maybe you could clarify where you found these terms used?

Comment: I'd assume this is a spelling mistake and you mean "net" instead of "nett" but it seems worth checking, before I suggest any edits to the question...

Comment: @Art Please see [this](https://boxofficeindia.com/movie.php?movieid=136)

Comment: @BillClark The spelling is according to the website mentioned in the comment above. I don't have any idea of the term **nett** while I'm aware of **net**.

Comment: Apparently it's just an alternate spelling of "net" ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(economics)

Comment: From a quick search, here's what I have. Gross is the amount of money from ticket sales. Net is subtracting taxes like sales tax. Adjusted I'm guessing it's adjusted for inflation.

Comment: Is there any other parameter beside inflation?